# input only year field of the datepicker calendarDateInput.js

Tags: javascript

i want to give my own value to the year field of the datepicker like

```
document.getElementById('endDate_Year_ID').value = '2013';
```

Is it possible to populate our own values with javascript ?

Comment: Are you using jquery UI datepicker? Can you show some code?

Comment: im using the datepicker calendarDateInput.js and taking the values like <script>DateInput('startDate', true, 'YYYY-MM-DD')</script>

Comment: You would have passed some hidden input with startDate right? Can you show that?

Comment: it is the same with both start date and end date. I only want to change the year text field of the date picker keeping the date and month the same

Comment: Did you try with `innerHTML()` ?

Comment: nope. it isn't working :(

Comment: So the script you are vaguely refering to is this one http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex7/jasoncalendar.htm? _More than easy_ to figure out that it gives the year inputfield an id `orderdate_Year_ID`, with the first part `orderdate` being the name giving during initialization. So just access that field via ID and set the new value …

Comment: yeah that is the script. But im unable to do so in the way i mentioned in the question part. The value is not getting reflected